# Selenium / JUnit 4 / Java 1.6 / Eclipse - Script terminates after 4 seconds with no error

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, junit

I am running my script and it terminates after 4 seconds.  Have been stuck on this for hours, any help very much appreciated.  Could it be that I may be using JUnit 3 code somewhere in a Junit 4 script?  Just a thought.  I am also calling a seperate PageObjects script, could this be the reason?  Code is below:

```
package com.testcases;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import jxl.*;
import com.PageObjects.RegisterUserPageObject;

import java.io.File;
import jxl.write.*;


public class RegisterUser {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

      @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://newtours.demoaut.com/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testRegisterUser() throws Exception {
      RegisterUserPageObject registerUserPage = PageFactory.initElements (driver, RegisterUserPageObject.class);

      Workbook wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:\\Users\\mce\\Documents\\Selenium\\Projects\\Mecury Tours\\Data1.xls"));
      WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("C:\\Users\\mce\\Documents\\Selenium\\Projects\\Mecury Tours\\Data2.xls"),wb);
      WritableSheet s = copy.getSheet(0);

      for(int i=1;i<s.getRows();i++)
            {

    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Register \n                    here')]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("firstName")).sendKeys("Tester");
    driver.findElement(By.name("lastName")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("lastName")).sendKeys("01");
    driver.findElement(By.name("phone")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("phone")).sendKeys("010101010");
    driver.findElement(By.id("userName")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("userName")).sendKeys("test@test.com");
    driver.findElement(By.name("address1")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("address1")).sendKeys("1 Test Ave");
    driver.findElement(By.name("city")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("city")).sendKeys("Dublin");
    driver.findElement(By.name("state")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("state")).sendKeys("Leinster");
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("country"))).selectByVisibleText("IRELAND");
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(s.getWritableCell("A"+i).getContents());
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("password");
    driver.findElement(By.name("confirmPassword")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("confirmPassword")).sendKeys("password");
    driver.findElement(By.name("register")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Home")).click();

    s.addCell(new Label(4,i,"Executed"));
            }
     copy.write();
     copy.close();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }

  private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
      driver.switchTo().alert();
      return true;
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      String alertText = alert.getText();
      if (acceptNextAlert) {
        alert.accept();
      } else {
        alert.dismiss();
      }
      return alertText;
    } finally {
      acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it open browser?

Comment: any stack maybe? which line?

Comment: If you debug, how far you get?

Comment: Try to add a breakpoint on this line `driver = new FirefoxDriver();` and go step by step... Or add some `System.out.println("something")` lines in "before area", "test area" and "after area" and tell us which is the latest line that was run before termination. Edit your post and add new details...